# Unable to unzip a file using 7z from Java on Linux machine

Tags: java, 7zip

I have a Java code that is running on a Linux machine. 
While the code is running it downloads certain files from the internet. Those '.Z' files, so i am trying to use the '7z' program to extract the data.

When trying to extract it manually everything work fine, the data ('.clk' file, basically a text file that could be open with notepad) is extracted perfectly and all the data is intact. But when i run it automatically using the java code, i get an error message and the extracted file is not full, seems like the extraction stops at the middle.

For manual extraction i use this command:

```
7z e filename.clk.Z -o/some/path/to/extract -aoa
```

While running it from Java i use this method:

```
public static void extractFile_linux(String inputFile, String outputDirectory) {
        try {
            new ProcessBuilder("7z", "e", inputFile, "-o" + outputDirectory, "-aoa").start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

The error message is:

```
Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 1050440 bytes (1026 KiB)

Extracting archive: /some/path/to/extract/igr19881.clk.Z
--
Path = /some/path/to/extract/igr19881.clk.Z
Type = Z

ERROR: Data Error : igr19881.clk

Sub items Errors: 1

Archives with Errors: 1

Sub items Errors: 1
```

This is the output from the manual command:

```
Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 1050462 bytes (1026 KiB)

Extracting archive: /some/path/to/extract/igr19881.clk.Z
--
Path = /some/path/to/extract/igr19881.clk.Z
Type = Z

Everything is Ok

Size:       4022169
Compressed: 1050462
```

What is the issue here?
Why am i not able to perform the extraction from Java?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to extract the same file? What is the output from the manual command?

Comment: What are the values you used for `inputFile`, `outputDirectory`?

Comment: I have added the output from the manual command. The values are the path to the zipped file and the output directory path, both as a string.

Comment: As the sizes of the files differ, I suspect one of the files is not complete. How did you download/create it?

Comment: I use the apache `FTPClient()`. `OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file2save));
   success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(file2get, os);`  I am using the same downloading method very often and it always worked for me.

Comment: @glglgl it seems that for some reason those files been not fully downloaded . Any idea why? When i run the same code on my laptop (Windows) it downloads them perfectly and extracts the data inside with out any issues.

Comment: @Dan: do you close the file after downloading? Yould be that there are some bytes left in the `BufferedOutputStream`.